# Ember data route model hook creating new record every transition

Tags: ember.js, ember-data

this code:

```
model(){
    return this.store.findRecord("user", this.get("session.data.authenticated.user_id"))
      .then(user => this.store.createRecord("info", {user}));
  },
```

creates a new record every time the route changes, meaning the data is lost on route switch, and the ember inspector shows a bunch of empty records.

I tried using fetchRecord instead of createRecord, but the entire app breaks.

```
.then(user => this.store.fetchRecord("info", {user}))
```

does anyone know how to prevent this?

Comment: Do you want to only load the info once per session?

Comment: Yes, they are going to need to be able to edit it too. Ideally when someone navigates away from that route they can still see the data that's entered when they return. Thanks for comment!

Comment: Take a look at services. You could store the user model locally and save it to the database each time a change is made (via observer).